# how to make ensure one active session per one user using python flask?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-login

how to make ensure one active session per one user using python flask?

**Description:** if one user logged in two different machines with same credentials
I want  mechanism to force logout earlier active sessions of that user with flask and python. Please help me out in this.

I am currently using `flask-login`, `load_user()` and `login_manager` libraries for login mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

One way for ensuring this would be by generating a session id from server. You would need to generate a unique session id every time a user logs in and store it in some database against that user. Apart from this you would need to authenticate user every time an endpoint call, which requires user to be logged in, is made. And of course discard the session id on logout.

This way whenever a user logs in the old session id is discarded and the previous session no more remains valid.

Comment: so i need to check in database for active one and discard the previous one's right

Comment: Yes. You could send the current session id of a user for verification in a request's header.